# How can i make docker to pull image from another host machine's local repository?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-pull

Please refer this link:

[Caching Docker Images](https://dev.to/mayeu/saving-time-and-bandwidth-by-caching-docker-images-with-a-local-registry-98b)

I have installed a local registry on Machine A, and it caches all the images I pull on Machine A.

Now, I am trying to pull some images on Machine B using Machine B's local repo. I cannot achieve it.

Machine A and B are on same network.

The ways I have tried.

1. Set up proxy configuration on Machine B and tried to route it.
2. Added the registry-mirrors set to remote machines local registry.

Nothing was fruitful. I am looking for help to achieve it.

Comment: What's the actual command you're running, and the actual error you're getting?  Are you `docker push`ing the images from A's local Docker to its registry before you try to `docker pull` them from B?

Comment: So whenever I pull it, it directly caches in my local registry. Now I am trying to use that same cache to use as a registry for other hosts. dev.to/mayeu/saving-time-and-bandwidth-by-caching-docker-images-with-a-local-registry-98b.